# Performing arithmetic operations on the elements in an array - android/java

Tags: java, android, arrays, logic

well the calculation in my app goes like this..

have a edittext box where the input(number) from the user is parsed to int as **nos**.

based on the input two other sets of edittext box appears.

if nos is 3 the 3 edittext from arrayOfEditText and 3 edittext from arrayOfEditText1 appears..
and the value entered in those sets of edittext are used for calculation.

the incomplete java code is below..

```
    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    chk();          
}       
});     
}   
public void chk()   {   
            EditText[] arrayOfEditText = new EditText[11];
            arrayOfEditText[1] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01));
            arrayOfEditText[2] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText02));
            arrayOfEditText[3] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText03));
            arrayOfEditText[4] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText04));
            arrayOfEditText[5] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText05));
            arrayOfEditText[6] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText06));
            arrayOfEditText[7] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText07));
            arrayOfEditText[8] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText08));
            arrayOfEditText[9] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText09));
            arrayOfEditText[10] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText10));

            EditText[] arrayOfEditText1 = new EditText[11];
            arrayOfEditText1[1] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText11));
            arrayOfEditText1[2] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText12));
            arrayOfEditText1[3] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText13));
            arrayOfEditText1[4] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText14));
            arrayOfEditText1[5] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText15));
            arrayOfEditText1[6] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText16));
            arrayOfEditText1[7] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText17));
            arrayOfEditText1[8] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText18));
            arrayOfEditText1[9] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText19));
            arrayOfEditText1[10] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText20));

            for(int i=1;i<=nos;i++)
            {
                if(arrayOfEditText[i].getText().toString().equals("")||arrayOfEditText1[i].getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dont leave points empty", 0).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    calcul();
                }
            }   }   public void calcul()    {       EditText[] arrayOfEditText = new EditText[11];
            arrayOfEditText[1] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01));
            arrayOfEditText[2] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText02));
            arrayOfEditText[3] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText03));
            arrayOfEditText[4] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText04));
            arrayOfEditText[5] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText05));
            arrayOfEditText[6] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText06));
            arrayOfEditText[7] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText07));
            arrayOfEditText[8] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText08));
            arrayOfEditText[9] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText09));
            arrayOfEditText[10] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText10));

            EditText[] arrayOfEditText1 = new EditText[11];
            arrayOfEditText1[1] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText11));
            arrayOfEditText1[2] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText12));
            arrayOfEditText1[3] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText13));
            arrayOfEditText1[4] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText14));
            arrayOfEditText1[5] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText15));
            arrayOfEditText1[6] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText16));
            arrayOfEditText1[7] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText17));
            arrayOfEditText1[8] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText18));
            arrayOfEditText1[9] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText19));
            arrayOfEditText1[10] = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText20));
                for(i=1;i<=nos;i++)
                {
                  //perform calculation
                }   }
```

now the logic to be performed in the **//perform calculation** area is..

arrayofedittext[1]*arrayofedittext1[1] + arrayofedittext[2]*arrayofedittext1[2] + arrayofedittext[3]*arrayofedittext1[3] + *etc based on **nos*** / arrayofedittext[1] + arrayofedittext[2] + arrayofedittext[3] + *etc based on **nos***

so can someone help me complete this coding?? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The less times you perform the same action the faster your app will run. So make `EditText[] arrayOfEditText` and `EditText[] arrayOfEditText1` class-scoped variables, define them once in onCreate() and you won't have to use findViewById() on `R.id.EditText**` after that point.

Here's a function that checks if any of the rows in the calculation are empty, if not you then `total` will have what you want.

```
public void calculateTotal() {
    String first;
    String second;

    double firstNum;
    double numerator = 0;
    double denominator = 0;

    // This loops counts from nos down to 1. It checks for empty strings and 
    //   sums up the numerator and denominator along the way.
    for(int index = nos; index > 0; index--) {
        first = arrayOfEditText[index].getText().toString();
        second = arrayOfEditText1[index].getText().toString();

        if(first.isEmpty() || second.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dont leave any points empty (" + (index + 1) + ")", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return; // Invalid input, warn user and bail out of function!
        }

        firstNum = Double.parseDouble(first);
        numerator += firstNum * Double.parseDouble(second);
        denominator += firstNum;
    }

    // Do something with total
    double total = numerator / denominator;
}
```

**Finer Points**

Define `arrayOfEditText` and `arrayOfEditText1` to be visible for the entire class like this:

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    EditText[] arrayOfEditText = new EditText[11];
    EditText[] arrayOfEditText1 = new EditText[11];
    ...

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            ...  
            arrayOfEditText[1] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
            etc, etc...
```

You should know that an array is a zero-index list. So the first entries in your arrays (`arrayOfEditText` and `arrayOfEditText1`) are *null*, if you ever try and reference `arrayOfEditText[0]` expecting an EditText your app will crash.

Lastly this code assumes that every EditText is a valid Double, if you don't restrict non-numeric entries already adding a check is quite simple.

Comment: thanks a lot man.. it worked!!
your post was very helpful to me, thanks!! :))

Comment: I'm not as conversant with Android. If you type any changes in EDITTEXT and presses calculate. Will then go through create again or just the clicklistener ?

Comment: @moskito-x This [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks) describes the lifecycle of an Android Activity. In short, onCreate() is only called by the OS when the Activity begins. Whenever the user clicks the `calculate` Button, the OnClickListener calls calculateTotal().

Comment: @kumareloaded Glad I could help, thanks for the upvote and marking the question as answered.

Comment: Sorry for that. How then `arrayOfEditText [x] =` filled with new values​​?

Comment: @moskito-x `arrayOfEditText[x]` is a link to the different EditTexts, this _will not_ change with user actions. `arrayOfEditText[x].getText().toString()` accesses the contents of the EditText, this _will_ change as the user enters new values. Hope that helps.

Comment: And the code for that is placed in OnCreate. Now i understand then you need no `addTextChangedListener`.

Comment: @Sam i still got some problems with finding the null(empty) values.. can you post the code for isEmpty() ??

Comment: @kumareloaded what have you expected ? onCreate all EditText's are empty

Comment: The function isEmpty() is a Java built-in method of the String data type, [read about it here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29) What error are you getting?

Comment: oops my bad.. i get "The method isEmpty() is undefined for the type string" error @Sam

Comment: Double check your capitalization `String name = ...` (what you want) is very different `string name = ...` (not what you want).

Comment: i've got it correct only man.. String first; and String second;
but still this error appears :(

Comment: Have you refreshed your import statements with crtl+shirt+o (check the import statements for any unwanted like `import android.R.string;` or `import <your package name>.R.string`) and then cleaned your project?

Comment: i dont have any unwanted imports and cleaned my projects couple of times.. nothing worked :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12642/discussion-between-sam-and-kumareloaded)

Answer (score 1):

**create global variables**

```
int[] intEditText new int[nos+1];
int[] intEditText1 new int[nos+1];
....
public void chk()   {   
int test=0;
try {

 for(int i=1;i<=nos+nos;i++) {
  if (i==1 && ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01))=="") {test=1;}
  if (i==2 && ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText02))=="") {test=1;}
   .....etc.
  if (i==11 && ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText11))=="") {test=1;}
  if (test==1) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dont leave points empty", 0).show();
    break;
  } else {
    if (i==1) {intEditText[i]:=Integer.parseInt(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText1));}
    if (i==2) {intEditText[i]:=Integer.parseInt(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText2));}
    .... etc.
    if (i==11) {intEditText1[i-nos]:=Integer.parseInt(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText11));}
    ....etc.

     calcul();
  {
 }


 } catch(NumberFormatException nbre) {
   System.out.println("Could not parse " + nbre);
 } 
}

public void calcul()    {
int myCalc;

  myCalc = intEditText[1]*intEditText[2]..... / (intEditText[1]*intEditText[2].....)
   //perform calculation
}
```